# Tensorflow Keras model.summary() shows 0 trainable parameters on a layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm training a LSTM variant, PhasedLSTM, for regression. I'm using tensorflow.contrib.rnn.PhasedLSTMCell which expects a vector of timestamps in addition to the features. Here's my model definition :

```
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, RNN, Input
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import PhasedLSTMCell

    hidden_size = 128
    num_features = 217
    num_timesteps = 2016

    input_layer_timestamps = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, 1), name='time_input')
    input_layer_features = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, num_features) name='data_input')

    timed_inputs = (input_layer_timestamps, input_layer_features)

    P_cell = PhasedLSTMCell(hidden_size)
    PLSTM_layer = RNN(P_cell, return_sequences=False, name='Phased_LSTM_1')(timed_inputs)

    output_layer = Dense(2, activation=None)(PLSTM_layer_1)

    model = Model(inputs  = [input_layer_timestamps, input_layer_features],
                  outputs = [output_layer])

    lstm_optimizer = Adam(lr=Adam_lr, clipnorm=5.)

    model.compile(optimizer=lstm_optimizer,
                  loss='mse')

    model.summary()
```

The model compiles and trains nicely. Validation results seem good, with reasonable error. However the output of model.summary() from the previous snippet is :

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
================================================================================================== 
time_input (InputLayer)         (None, 2016, 1)      0                

__________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
data_input (InputLayer)         (None, 2016, 217)    0                

__________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
Phased_LSTM_1 (RNN)             (None, 128)           0           time_input[0][0]                 
                                                                 data_input[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            66          Phased_LSTM_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 258 Trainable params: 258 Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Notably with the number of trainable parameters 0 for Phased_LSTM_1

If model.weights() is then called, it does not show the LSTM part at all :

```
ipdb> NN.weights
[<tf.Variable 'scope/dense/kernel:0' shape=(128, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'scope/dense/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>]
```

Additionally if the model is then saved with model.save() and loaded with either 
tensorflow.keras.models.load_model or defining model -> model.load() the model will behave completely differently. The reasonably good validation accuracy will change into a model that predicts only noise, i.e. it looks like the original fairly good regression model was changed from a RNN into something that indeed looks like a 128-neuron single layer NN with linear activation trained on the wrong thing.

I have three questions:

1) What's going on? Is this a bug or just me abusing the Keras RNN API?

2) How can I verify that the LSTM is being trained properly? I want to inspect the layers like I would normally with model.weights and model.get_weights()

3) How can I save and load this model without breaking it? My input and output pipelines and the module around it are built for Keras, so I'd rather not convert the NN definition to 'base' tensorflow if possible.

I'm using tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 with Keras 2.2.4-tf

Comment: You are abusing the API unfortunately, Keras only deals with `Layer` types whereas you import from `contrib.rnn` that has nothing to do with Keras so it doesn't know how to deal with it properly. You might be able to wrap it in a Keras layer, have a look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).